# how to do i fix this error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)(objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker-errors, ios9

I'm having this issue when I try to compile my code. Can anyone help me out with it ?

```
Ld /Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Good_Guy-dsioapagqxznqrcxoglnhzgzvswx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Good\ Guy.app/Good\ Guy normal arm64
cd "/Users/Alex/Desktop/Good Guy"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -L/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Good_Guy-dsioapagqxznqrcxoglnhzgzvswx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Good_Guy-dsioapagqxznqrcxoglnhzgzvswx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Good_Guy-dsioapagqxznqrcxoglnhzgzvswx/Build/Intermediates/Good\ Guy.build/Debug-iphoneos/Good\ Guy.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Good\ Guy.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Good_Guy-dsioapagqxznqrcxoglnhzgzvswx/Build/Intermediates/Good\ Guy.build/Debug-iphoneos/Good\ Guy.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Good\ Guy_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Good_Guy-dsioapagqxznqrcxoglnhzgzvswx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Good\ Guy.app/Good\ Guy

duplicate symbol _HighScoreNumber in:
/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Good_Guy-dsioapagqxznqrcxoglnhzgzvswx/Build/Intermediates/Good Guy.build/Debug-iphoneos/Good Guy.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GameViewController.o
/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Good_Guy-dsioapagqxznqrcxoglnhzgzvswx/Build/Intermediates/Good Guy.build/Debug-iphoneos/Good Guy.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , your question will most certainly be closed unless you edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Check the variable _HighScoreNumber. Probably you have defined it (for example int _HighScoreNumber = 0;) in both files GameViewController and ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I could not understand your question completely due to formatting but these are two most common occurring instances that can cause it 
- you might have `import` a `.m` file instead of `.h`
- or go in target - build phases - compile sources , you might have some duplicate files there.